# Two onclick functions in the same button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm a New beginner programmer and i cant even figure out how to fix this so please help:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('but1').style.display='block'""document.getElementById('but2').style.display='block'">Klik!</button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the double-double-quotes with a semicolon:

```
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('but1').style.display='block';document.getElementById('but2').style.display='block'">Klik!</button
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery

```js
$('#btn').click(function () {

$('#but1').css("display", "block");
$('#but2').css("display", "block");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id="btn" type="button">Klik!</button>



<button id="but1" type="button">But1!</button>


<button id="but2" type="button">But2!</button>
```